# Where should I put extra methods?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have extra codes that are not applied to the view. It is not a model and is not part of the URL. It is just a code that increments a default number to a number field of a model. Should I put this method inside the models.py file?

Remembering that I use the django framework.

This is method:

```
def increment_process_number():
    year_date = now().year
    year_atual = int(year_date)
    last_number = Process.objects.all().filter(date__year=year_atual).order_by('number').last()
    if not last_number:
        new_number = 1
        return new_number
    else:
        number = last_number.number
        number_int = int(number)
        new_number = number_int + 1
        return new_number
```

Prioritizing good development practices, where should I save this method.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in this cases I create a file called `utils.py` inside a `core` app that is supposed to keep the general stuff used by the entire project, like custom permissions, custom context processors, midlewares, generic views or utilities functions like yours.

You will end up with something like this: `your_project/core/utils.py`.

And wherever you want to use it, you can just import it:

```
from core.utils import increment_process_number
```

Comment: This method is depending on the `Process` model. If you put it in `core/utils.py` and call it from `models.py` you will get circular import problem, so I would suggest putting the method in `models.py`.

Comment: Right, we should import the django apps helper: `from django.apps import apps` and then import the Model: `Process = apps.get_model(app_label='my_app', model_name='Process')`

Comment: This function can also be a `@classmethod` inside the `Process` Model. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod

Comment: Very good suggestion to use the decorator @classmethod. That way the code does not look ugly. Now it's more organized. In case of codes that do not depend on some model, just create a core directory, correct?

Comment: Hey @DaniloRodrigues, `core` is a new app that you should to create, just run the `python manage.py startapp core` and then add it to your `iNSTALLED_APPS` settings config. But if you choose the new app solution, you should pay attention to @ivan comment, in order to prevent the circular import problem.